# Is it possible to create a parallel entry in Linked Table per Type In EF6.x using code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Consider the following database structure (created using EF Code First)

[image]

Using simple code as illustrated below I can easily add either new Customers or Suppliers;

```
    private static void InsertCustomers()
    {
        var customer1 = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Mickey",
            LastName = "Mouse",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now
        };

        var customer2 = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Fred",
            LastName = "Flintstone",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now
        };

        using (var context = new ContactsContext())
        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write; //purely for logging
            context.Customers.Add(customer1);
            context.Customers.Add(customer2);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My question is simple.  Fred Flintstone could at some point in the future become a supplier as well as remaining a Customer. From within SSMS I can easily achieve this but I would obviously like to do this from within the application itself. If I use the syntax

```
var sup = new Supplier();
```

then the underlying logic will create a new Id (which is perfectly sensible, but undesired as I want to use the existing Id assigned to Fred Flinstone as a Customer which is 2) so how do I in effect add an existing  Contacts.Id into the Suppliers table so that it becomes a Primary / foreign key using code in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would transpire that this is not as intuitive in Code First as one might have thought so I have reverted to using the following which does work as intended;

```
   static void CreateSupplier(int id)
    {

        var contactId = id; //the id being passed in would have been collected from a list of Customers, as we want Fred Flintstone it would have been set to 2
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        using (var context = new ContactsContext())


        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write; //purely for logging
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
               "INSERT INTO Contacts.Suppliers(Id, DateStarted) VALUES({0}, {1})", contactId, date);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
```

It's possible that there is a way to do this with a lambda but at present I haven't found one.